# How to create a new "stable" branch in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, visualhg

I use Mercurial (with VisualHg) for my source code and I have the following situation.

I'm currently using the default branch and would like to follow the procedure shown at http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/05/mercurial-workflows-stable-default/ to create a new stable branch.

Here are my questions:

1. I have created a release, tagged it and then I would like to move it to the stable branch (which currently doesn't exist). How can I do that?
2. One I have that new branch how do I create two folders on my machine so that one contains the default and the other the stable data?

I'm not sure if this approach works properly with Mercurial: I used to use VisualSVN.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a `stable` branch using `VisualHg` follow the following steps:

1. Click the **Update to Revision** button in Visual Studio
2. In the **Update to:** drop down, select your tag and then press **Update**
3. Click the **Commit** button in Visual Studio
4. Click on the **Branch: default** button above the commit message
5. Select **Open a new named branch**, type in `stable` into the box next to it and press **Ok**
6. Type in a relevant message - perhaps "Create stable branch"
7. Press the **Commit** button and confirm that you want to create the new branch.

This has created your `stable` branch and it has the contents of your release except that the tag that you created is still on the `default` branch.  If you want to move it, you can do that from the workbench as follows:

1. Click on **Repo Browser** button in Visual Studio
2. Right click on the last revision on `stable` and click on **Tag...** on the pop up menu
3. Select your tag from the drop down list
4. Expand the options section and check **Replace existing tag (-f/--force)**
5. Click **Move** followed by **Close**

If you are working with a central repository then you'll need to specify that you want to push the new branch by clicking on the **Options** button of the TortoiseHg Sync window and ticking the **Allow push of a new branch (--new-branch)** before you push the change.

In the future, you would merge from `default` to `stable` and then tag `stable` when you want to make another release.  To merge changes from `default` into `stable` do the following:

1. Click on **Repo Browser** button in Visual Studio
2. Find the latest change in `stable`, right click and then click **Update...**
3. Find the latest change in `default`, right click then click **Merge with local...**
4. Click **Next**
5. The next page might tell you that you need to resolve conflicts - to do that click on the blue underlined **resolved** and resolve the conflicts in the pop up dialog by selecting the conflict in the top box and pressing the desired button on the right.
6. The next page should say "No merge conflicts, ready to commit" - click **Next**
7. Accept the default message or overwrite with your own and press **Commit Now**
8. Press **Finish**

To merge the other way, update to `default` in step one and merge from `stable` in step 3.

To have two folders on your machine for one to contain `default` and the other `stable`, you would simply clone the repository a second time and keep one updated to the `default` branch and the other updated to the `stable` branch.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very detailed instructions, Steve. They are much appreciated. I was able to setup the stable branch.
Can you tell me how I would go about merging the changes between the two branches? I guess it should do both (when I do a bugfix in stable I should move it to default) and when I do a new release I should move it from default to stable.

Comment: I've added details of merging into the answer